# Twitter API 401 - weird

Tags: twitter

¨
I have a weird reponse from Twitter API. It's Error 401: Unauthorized, but the weird thing is, that it has worked before.

I created a twitter app several days before and generate access token by twitter developers portal. Everything works fine for 18 hours. Then, the service reports 401. Today, I created a new app and update the access settings - consumer key, access token and so on. I did one API call and everything worked fine. But after next request, twitter returned 401.

I have read a lot scenarios when the twitter returns 401 error but I don't know why Twitter returns the error to me.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

I may sound silly but please check if date and time of the PC or server where the app is installed.
For example if you set your timezone as GMT in your PC then your PC must have exact time of GMT else twitter API will through error. Please check it.

Thanks

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer. I have set UTC+1:00 on my PC and time is synchronized with microsoft time server.

Comment: Can you please paste the API call in which you are getting error, so i can zero in on the bug :) Your credentials may be missing or not valid, please check this link https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses